# Wrap bash functions into a runner function

Tags: bash

My [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script contains many `mysqldump blabla > dump.sql` and `mysq balbla < dump.sql` in order to make it possible to run it in *dry-run* mode.

Actually the point is to create a funtion `run` to run anything I ask it to.

```
  run echo 'hello world'
  run mysqldump blabla > dump.sql
  run mysql blabla < dump.sql
  run ssh blabla
  # etc


run() {
    if [[ "$(printenv DRY_RUN)" = "yes" ]]
    then
        echo "${@}"
    else
        ${@}
    fi
}
```

However, this is doesn't work:

```
run "mysqldump -uuser -ppass dbase > dump.sql"
```

I get this error:

> mysqldump: couldn't find table: ">"

Comment: @HaukeLaging I did try it and when it worked I accepted it... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433987/wrap-bash-functions-into-a-runner-function#comment783613_433993

Comment: `$(printenv DRY_RUN)`? Why not just `$DRY_RUN`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `"${@}"` instead of `${@}` (like with `echo "${@}"`) but that is not the reason for your problem.

The reason is that redirection takes places very early in command line parsing, before parameter substitution. Thus after the variable has put `>` in the command line, the shell is not looking for `>` any more.

An important point which I noticed after I published my answer: With a call like

```
run mysqldump blabla > dump.sql
```

the function `run` does not see `>` and `dump.sql`. That is probably not what you want because it prevents you from changing all the redirections with a single environment variable, as the output of `echo "${@}"` is redirected to the file then, too. Thus, you should use something like `run --redirect dump.sql mysqldump blabla`, see below.

There are two possibilities:

1. Stick with `"$@"` and use `eval`. This may take you to a quoting nightmare, of course. You have to quote everything except for the `>` so that the shell sees a bare `>` in the command line before it does quote removal.
2. Handle the redirection separately:

   ```
   run --redirect dump.sql mysqldump blabla

   run() {
       if [ "$1" == '--redirect' ]; then
           shift
           redirect_target="$1"
           shift
       else
           redirect_target='/dev/stdout' # works at least with Linux
       fi

       if [[ "$(printenv DRY_RUN)" = "yes" ]]
       then
           echo "${@}"
       else
           "${@}" > "$redirect_target"
       fi
   }
   ```

   You can avoid the `redirect_target='/dev/stdout'` if you put the `if [ "$1" == '--redirect' ]` in the `else` branch of `if [[ "$(printenv DRY_RUN)" = "yes" ]]`.

   ```
       if [[ "$(printenv DRY_RUN)" = "yes" ]]
       then
           if [ "$1" == '--redirect' ]; then
               # do not output "--redirect file"
               shift
               shift
           fi
           echo "${@}"
       else
           if [ "$1" == '--redirect' ]; then
               shift
               redirect_target="$1"
               shift
               "${@}" > "$redirect_target"
           else
               "${@}"
           fi
       fi
   ```

Comment: This answer presumes 1) the redirection will always be output redirection, when it could be input redirection; 2) that only output redirection will ever be desired, when both output and input redirection may be desirable for some future command.

Comment: @user1404316 That is right but on the one hand it would be easy to modify my code accordingly and on the other hand it makes sense to assume that you want to be able to switch the output but not the input because a command which works on input just doesn't work right without this input. Thus you just might stick to `run mysql blabla < dump.sql`

Answer (score 0):

Like in [another recent answer I posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433786/70524), word splitting happens too late to initiate redirection (but not too late to affect redirection).

You can run the command using `eval`, like suggested in another answer in the linked post, or using `bash -c "$*"`, while still having to quote the entire command line including redirections.

Though if you want to avoid having to quote the commands, one option is to set `-nv` (`noexec` and `verbose`), so that bash doesn't run the commands but merely prints them. So, instead of a wrapper `run`, at the start of the script, do:

```
[[ $DRY_RUN = yes ]] && set -nv
```

Comment: What does this have to do with word splitting?

Comment: @HaukeLaging OP using an unquoted `$@`, presumably in the hopes of having bash see `>` and do something with it.

Comment: Sure but that is not word splitting but parameter expansion. There is no word splitting to be done on `>` anyway.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Obviously OP knows to use a quoted `"$@"` elsewhere, but they used an *unquoted* `$@` there, and passed the command line including redirections as a single string. That's why it's about word splitting. (Also, isn't word splitting part of parameter expansion, anyway?)

Answer (score -1):

Use `"$@"` (with the double quotes):

```
run() {
    if [[ "$(printenv DRY_RUN)" = "yes" ]]
    then
        echo "${@}"
    else
    "$@"
    fi
}
```

Without them, `$@` expands to a single token.

Comment: Everything about this answer is wrong.

Comment: @HaukeLaging it works for me, what's wrong with this solution?

Comment: @smarber Neither `"$@"` nor `$@` performs redirection. See my answer. If you have tested it then you misunderstand the test result. The second wrong part: Neither `"$@"` nor `$@` is expanded to a single token (`"$*"` is). The difference is that `$@` is expanded to several unquoted tokens and `"$@"` is expanded to quoted tokens.

Comment: @HaukeLaging when I run `run mysqldump blabla > dump.sql` I get a dump file filled with the right data. However when I run `run mysqldump blabla` I get the output of `mysqldump`. This is how I hoped the `run` function behave.

Comment: @smarber and did you test it in dry run mode?

Comment: @smarber It makes a big difference whether you want redirection performed inside or outside your `run` function. I would think that it makes little sense to do that outside if you already have a `run` function which should be flexible. You could use two levels of dry run: one showing the command and another running the command without redirection.

Comment: @muru I just did and it does not work, indeed. So only the not dry run mode work. Thanks for point that out

Comment: @HaukeLaging sorry I was just talking about the non dry run mode. So now I see (I hope) your point and you're right...